# NullReferenceException when searching for data in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

Hi I've written this code to search for cardserial in a gridview. But I get an error :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Could you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Debug and tell which line is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if value in the cell is not null (if it is calling `ToString` on it fails)

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    var serial = row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value;

    if (serial != null && serial.ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, of the following is null, which is causing the exception when you dereference it:

- `dataGridView2`
- `row.Cells["CardSerial"]`
- `row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value`
- `textBox2`
- <strike>`dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index]`</strike>
- `dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle`

To find out which one, debug your program, and make use of the watch window, immediate window, or add a number of debug/trace output lines.

Of specific note may be the case where `row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value` is null.

Comment: *"To find out which one, debug your program"* +1

Comment: I think `dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index]` cannot be null if the `row.Index` is not out of range. Otherwise the exception `IndexOutOfRangeException` will be thrown instead.

Comment: @KingKing Yes, I believe that's quite correct, especially since the index comes from the row itself anyway (not sure why the OP doesn't just use `row.DefaultCellStyle`)